# Multithreading introduction - running 2 loops at one time

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I am trying to make a loop independent of one another, because the 2nd one is waiting for an input using raw_input(). To do that, I have found that the best way of doing this is multithreading, and I am trying to figure out how that works. I wrote this:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
def loopA():
    while True:
        print "1"
        time.sleep(1)
def loopB():
    while True:
        print "2"
        time.sleep(1)
threadA = Thread(target = loopA)
threadB = Thread(target = loopB)
threadA.run()
threadB.run()

threadA.join()
threadB.join()
```

What I`d expect to see is a row of 1s and 2s being printed into the shell, but all it does is just a row of 1s. How to get the 2nd thread involved as well?

Edit: OK so I have moved:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
def loopA():
    while True:
        print "1"
        time.sleep(1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Thread(target = loopA).start()
    while True:
        n = raw_input("enter here:")
        print n
```

What I want now is the 1 being printed over and over again, and whenever I write something and hit return, it should just get printed, but the loop of 1s should never stop.

Comment: your second code works for me... What are you getting?

Comment: Your threads are competing for a non-synchronized resource, specifically the console.  If I set loopA's loop to sleep 10, I can type in "12345" and wait for the print, then continue typing "67890" and the raw_input gets "67890".  The print statement forced the console to discard everything and start over with the raw_input.

Comment: the 2nd code: I want the 1 be printed every seccond, even if i am writing the input and didn`t press return yet. The input stops the process and waits until I hit return, I want it not to colide with the loop at all.

Comment: Have you run in a terminal or are you using an ide? The behavior Kenny described is what should happen

Comment: i am using both IDLE and shell, as well as Geany IDE. Yes, what Kenny wrote is right, but I want the loopA to print whenever it is time to, regardless if I am currently typing the input.

Comment: Well, I'm using python 3.6 so I can't be 1000000% sure, but I can't reproduce the issue then.. Are you using the exact code as posted in the question?

Comment: Im in python 2.7, and yes, the code is the same. at me - as long as I don't return the input, no more 1s are being printed...

Comment: Just one more thing - the end result will not be used to print stuff, it will add some score to a variable repeatably - so I need the loop to never stop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for with your second example where you poll for an input, because it seems to work as I would expect. As for your first example, you used `Thread.run()` instead of `Thread.start()`. The `run` attribute is a reference to the actual callable (in this case `target`) and is provided for subclassing to make thread classes. calling `run()` does not start a new thread of execution, but rather just calls the target function within the main thread. This is why your second thread is never started in the first example. Changing from `run` to `start` fixes this problem.

Comment: the second issue may be OS dependent

Comment: @KennyOstrom not in the [current release](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/threading.py#L474) at least.. `run` is a dead simple "call the target" function with a little protection to avoid self referencing.

Comment: that helped, still not yet in my goal tho. It did what I wanted, but (see the comments on my original post), once the raw_input() function is called, it stops until I write something into it.

Comment: By "the second issue" I am referring to the same thing you mention in the first line, where you say "I'm not sure what you are looking for with your second example where you poll for an input".

Comment: @KennyOstrom gotcha.. yah, file stream buffering is likely a main driving factor here, and I'm not as familiar with that.